# Expression might contain invalid token SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I try to execute a simple sql task with variable, so I create my variable and into it I insert delete statement like:

```
DELETE FROM fiscal_cxp WHERE EMPRESA = '"+@[User::cia]+"'
```

but when I try to evaluate expression I get an issue:

[image]

I review query several times but I dont find nothing wrong. Can someone knows what is wrong there? Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the opening and closing quotes:

```
"DELETE FROM fiscal_cxp WHERE EMPRESA = '" + @[User::cia] + "'"
```

Comment: It´s true, I hate when that thing happen.. Thanks!

Comment: @Pepe if this answer solved your issue, then you have to accept it. just click on the mark below the voting arrows. You can visit the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) for more informations